# WCF Service 405 Error When Using Proxy

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that works perfectly fine unless I attempt to use a proxy in the communication stream such as:

```
AnonClient anonService = new AnonClient();  
var bindHttp = anonService.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;  
bindHttp.ProxyAddress = new Uri("http://149.169.227.131:3127");  
bindHttp.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;  
bindHttp.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
```

As soon as the proxy is introduced - and it can be any proxy - IIS immediately rejects the request with a 405 error.  There is no authentication occurring at the IIS level - I take of everything in code - anonymous access is enabled - so what is wrong with my IIS configuration?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: As it turns out the proxies themselves are throwing the 405 error - not IIS.  Is there some way to make my WCF service more proxy-friendly?

Comment: Just to close this loop, the issue was using an Open Proxy with a WCF service which, by default, emits SOAP.  Most open proxies block SOAP and were shutting things down.  The solution is actually simple - add JSON attributes on top of the WCF service calls and run over the RESTful interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this loop, the issue was using an Open Proxy with a WCF service which, by default, emits SOAP. Most open proxies block SOAP and were shutting things down. The solution is actually simple - add JSON attributes on top of the WCF service calls and run over the RESTful interface